# Modificar objetos dentro de archvios creados con ObjetInputStream/ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, poo

Buenas a todos, tengo un problema a la hora de modificar objetos dentro de archivos creados con ObjectInput/ObjectOutput Stream, tengo un fichero con objetos tipo user guardados en un fichero llamado user.dat, a estos objetos tipo user con variable int points, ocupo entrar al objeto que guarde por medio del nombre de usuario, agregarle valor a la variable points y guardarlo, de manera tal que cuando vuelva a ingresar al sistema con este usuario, los puntos esten con el valor que les deje anteriormente. gracias

Comment: Para ayudarte necesitamos que proveas un [mcve]

Comment: Creo que la forma más segura de hacerlo sin corromper el archivo en el cuál se guarda el objeto es: **deserializando** el objeto guardado del archivo (es decir, con el **ObjectInputStream** lees el archivo con el objeto, lo conviertes a **user**), luego tomas ese objeto le modificas el campo **points** con el nuevo valor y lo vuelves a **serializar** como lo hiciste con el **ObjectOutputStream**

Comment: @C.Rodriguez al final asi lo hice, muchas gracias

Comment: @iHackTime, Es siempre un placer ;-)